# How to find out which document a certain trigger belongs to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am a beginner of Google Apps Script(gas) and have a question that I can't solve by myself.

Is there anyone who knows which document a certain trigger is working on.

The reason why I am asking this is I would like to know how functions on the trigger list are defined. In the example below (I got it from google image), I would like to know which document has the function 'purgeGmail' in it, so that I can take a look at and edit it.

[image]

Could anyone please answer my question if you can?

My first language is not English, so if this post does not make sense, please let me know. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know there are two kinds of scripts namely:

- standalone scripts
- bound scripts

Since you mentioned a script belonging to a document, I think you are referring to [bound scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script). Here's how to do it:

1. Open your Google document.
2. Under 'Tools' menu, click 'Script Editor'. This directs you to a script editor.
3. Click 'Resources' menu and choose 'All your triggers'. All triggers you see here belongs to your document.

**NOTE**: The important things is you open the script editor by opening your Google document first.